# How can I place correctly GridView, ListView and Column?

Tags: flutter, material-ui

I have a ListView.builder() in a route builder:

```
class PlansPage extends StatelessWidget {
    _myList = List of some typed data;
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // here there are scaffold -> body -> container
      return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (_, i) => Divider(height: 1.0),
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => FullPlan(
                cityArea: _myList[i].cityArea,
                telephone: _myList[i].telephone,
                days: _myList[i].days,
              ),
              itemCount: _myList.length,
            );
  }
}
```

Each element created by the ListView is a StatelessWidget, here coded:

```
class FullPlan extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final String cityArea;
  @required
  final String telephone;
  @required
  final List<ADay> days;
  FullPlan({
    this.cityArea,
    this.telephone,
    this.days,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          // I haven't done RichText yet
          Text('City: ' + cityArea),
          // Image
          Text('Phone mumber: ' + telephone),
          GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3),
              itemCount: days.length,
              // I haven't created 'ADay' sub-object yet
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text('day element'),
          ),
        ],
      );
}
```

I receive error by the console, not by the analyzer.

I want to create an element like this:

[image]

for each FullPlan widget.

Now there is a ListView builder that for each object contains a Column, that contains Text, Image and GridView, that contains 10-15 sub-objects.

I think the error comes from the arrangement of the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 2.0**

Taking your requirements into consideration, all you want is **the Layout without having `GridView()` to scroll**

Now, `GridView()` comes with a scrolling, and if you try to use [NeverScrollableScrollPhysics class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html), to disable the scrolling in `GridView`, it will eventually disable scrolling in `ListView` as well.

The workaround for you is to use [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html), which is a very useful widget in this case. Works like `GridView()` only. With some modifications, you will be able to achieve what you want

We will be removing the `GridView`, and replace it with `Wrap` in your `FullPlan`. Rest will be same. *I have just played with the height only. And added `color` to `Divider` to make it look prominent on your UI*

```
      Container(
        // this is to just show you how much space is being taken by 
        // this widget, remove this, cos it is not required
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 8.0,
          runSpacing: 4.0,
          children: days.map((item) => Text(item)).toList().cast<Widget>()
        )
      )
```

You will be able to see the difference, the moment you will look into the full code. Here is the full code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // just taking some random number for the length
  List _myList = [1,2,3];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (_, i) => Divider(thickness: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => FullPlan(
            cityArea: "Dummy City Area",
            telephone: "+91 999999999",
            days: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'],
          ),
          itemCount: _myList.length,
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class FullPlan extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final String cityArea;
  @required
  final String telephone;
  @required
  final List<String> days; // to make it work for the time being
  FullPlan({
    this.cityArea,
    this.telephone,
    this.days,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      // I haven't done RichText yet
      Text('City: ' + cityArea),
      // Image
      Text('Phone mumber: ' + telephone),
      // You actually need to specify the height for the GridView via
      // container
      Container(
        // this is to just show you how much space is being taken by 
        // this widget, remove this, cos it is not required
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
          runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
          children: days.map((item) => Text(item)).toList().cast<Widget>()
        )
      )
    ]
  );
}
```

**Important** You can play with `spacing` and `runspacing` as per your UI needs. It would work just fine.

And here is the result with a GIF representation of it, to make you understand better.

[image: Result GIF]

Let me know, if this was the end goal only :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it clear enough. I want to create a GridView but not scrollable, only the ListView will be scrollable. The Grid will be used only to show 2 or 3 widgets per row.

Comment: I was wondering that as well. Then, I would make changes in the code, and not use GridView then, but something else, which will work like this `GridView` but not scrollable? Will that do @dam034?

Comment: Hey @dam034 I have changed my answer aligning to your final requirement. **Answer 2.0**, feel free to give out your thoughts on it. All the very best!

Comment: I have followed your code, creating Wrap, and now it works!

Comment: Wonderful. Glad it worked for you @dam034. Happy learning and all the very best :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider **slivers**. It allows you to combine lists, grids and other elements into a single scrollable widget. It also includes some cool features like the `SliverAppBar` with flexible space that shrinks as you scroll down.

Check those links out :

Youtube : [SliverList & SliverGrid (Flutter Widget of the week)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM)

Medium : [Flutter — Slivers and CustomScrollView](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-slivers-and-customscrollview-1aaadf96e35a)